# In all ios devices and safari browser, open in new tab redirects to base url, not redirecting to expected route (Angular)

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, angular, window.open

I am trying to open a route in new tab by using window.open.
In all ios devices and safari browser, open in new tab redirects to base url, not redirecting to expected route (Angular). Not even working with window.open
I tried with anchor tag with `target=_blank` but gives same issue.

`window.open(this.getRoutePrefix() + '/new-page', '_blank', 'noopener');`

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue when trying to open a link with "window.open()". Does it work with Firefox (Desktop) for your? If your Firefox thinks that your link is a popup (as in my case), Safari might think that, too. In my case, I disabled popup blocking in the iPhone's Safari settings, and that solved it.